Почему чтение и построчный вывод файла в Python гораздо медленнее, чем в AutoIt?
Для сравнения скорости Python и AutoIt запустил скрипты с одинаковой задачей - прочитать файл из 60.000 строк. Результаты удивили.
Вот скрипт Python:
with open('Тест.txt') as testfile:
for stroka in testfile:
      print(stroka, end="")

Время выполнения составило 2 мин 20 сек
Вот скрипт AutoIt:
#include <File.au3>
$FileToTest = FileOpen(@ScriptDir & '\Тест.txt',  $FO_READ)
While  @error <> -1
    $Stroka = FileReadLine(@ScriptDir & '\Тест.txt')
    ConsoleWrite($Stroka & @CRLF)
WEnd
FileClose( @ScriptDir & '\Тест.txt')
Exit

Время выполнения составило 20 сек! Неужели Python действительно такой медленный? Как это можно объяснить?

Думаю, что основная задача здесь - все-таки не чтение, а печать. Это самая медленная операция в этом коде

Во втором случае вы никуда вывод скрипта не перенаправляли? Чтение делается моментально, вот вывод на экран может (и будет) тормозить. Хотя и странно, что настолько по-разному он тормозит.

Вывод в консоль делали оба скрипта. Условия одинаковы. Но разница просто огромна. Вот в чем и вопрос.

Вообще вы привели некорректный код для AutoIt, он вообще-то должен зациклиться. Ну либо я чего-то не понимаю. Вы не используете открытый дескриптор файла $FileToTest и читаете первую строку из файла каждый раз в цикле, открывая его заново по имени. Если это реальный код, то работать он может только каким-то чудом (почему-то не удаётся прочитать файл в какой-то момент и тогда его цикл прекращается). Нормально этот код вообще не должен работать. И он не соответствует коду на Python, это разный код. Второй код должен выводить одну и ту же строку файла - первую.

Да, согласен. Код AutoIt не корректный, (запутался в экспериментах :-)). Но тестирование проходило на корректных кодах. И как выше подсказали уважаемые  Алексей Р и CrazyElf причиной действительно являлось медленное выполнение print(). Без вывода в консоль время выполнения составило для AutoIt 1.55 сек, а для Python 0.085 сек. Тестирование производилось без компиляции. И, замечаю, для Autoit всегда минимальное время выполнения 1 -1,5 сек. По видимому AutoIt загружает исполнительный модуль. Всем спасибо!

С печатью в консоль 0.241c, с перенаправлением в файл 0.058с. Вы аккуратнее время  меряйте.

С использованием моего скрипта для python у вас получилось 0.241c ? Странно... В качестве файла, вы читали файл с 60000 строками?
